# How to display Both Label and Value using single Tag in LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components

Migrating Visualforce page to LWC:

Vf page code :

```
   <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
            <apex:outputLabel value="{!$ObjectType.Account.fields.Discount_1__c.label}" for="CurrentAccountDiscount_1__c"/>
            <apex:outputLabel value="{!CurrentAccount.Discount_1__c}" />
        </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
```

{!CurrentAccount.Discount_1__c} - From Apex.

Tried below syntax in LWC:

```
   <lightning-formatted-rich-text label={$ObjectType.Account.fields.CDW__c.label} 
                                value={CurrentAccount.Discount_1__c}></lightning-formatted-rich-text>
```

**Label value isn't  showing in  User Interface**. How to display value and Label LIKE Visualforce page, Trying to find almost equivalent tag in LWC.

Is there anyway to display Label and Value in **a single Tag.**

It Looks Like Below in VF Page:

**Discount : 10**

Answer (score 3):

`$ObjectType.Account.fields.CDW__c.label` this sintax won't work in LWC.
You must reference a variable defined in your JS class.
You could use [getObjectInfo](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/reference_wire_adapters_object_info) to retrieve information about SObject.

**JS**

```
import ACCOUNT_OBJECT from '@salesforce/schema/Account';
import { getObjectInfo } from 'lightning/uiObjectInfoApi';
```

```
discountLabel;

@wire(getObjectInfo, { objectApiName: ACCOUNT_OBJECT })
getAccountInfo({ data, error }) {
    if (data) {
        this.discountLabel = data.fields.Discount_1__c.label;
    }
}
```

Anyway [lightning-formatted-rich-text](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-formatted-rich-text/specification) doesn't have a label attribute, so you have to inline it and the field value using css. [SLDS](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/utilities/grid/) provides almost every class you need.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127542/discussion-between-annappa-and-glls).